# У Bottom Navigator не меняется backgroudColor

Tags: flutter

Вроде делаю все верно, но не пойму почему цвет не меняется
Часть кода из навигатора

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/pages/HomePage.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/pages/ProfilePage.dart';

class BottomNavigator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavigatorState createState() => _BottomNavigatorState();
}

class _BottomNavigatorState extends State<BottomNavigator> {
  int _sectionIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: mainBackgroudColor,
      body: _sectionIndex == 0 ? HomePage() : ProfilePage(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.directions_run_outlined),
            label: 'Run',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.group_outlined ,),
            label: 'Group',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person_outlined),
            label: 'Account',
          )
        ],
        currentIndex: _sectionIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.red,
        unselectedItemColor: iconColor,
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        backgroundColor: backgroudColorBottomNavigation,
        iconSize: 32,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _sectionIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: можно чуть больше кода? backgroundColor: backgroudColorBottomNavigation должно отрабатывать

Comment: @Maxgmer добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `BottomNavigationBar` нужно добавить параметр: `type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,`

Или в `BottomNavigationBarItem` добавить параметр: `backgroundColor: Colors.green,`

> {Color? backgroundColor}
>
> The color of the BottomNavigationBar itself.
>
> If type is BottomNavigationBarType.shifting and the items have
> BottomNavigationBarItem.backgroundColor set, the items'
> backgroundColor will splash and overwrite this color.